# Finding the 3 most recently modified files in a long list of files

Tags: java, file, sorting, memory, memory-management

I have a file list which I want to sort and extract the top 3 last modified.

Constraint: I cannot use Java 7 due to compatibility issues on downstream apps

### My current options

#### Solution 1

```
File[] files = directory.listFiles();    
Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>(){
    public int compare(File f1, File f2)
    {
        return Long.valueOf(f1.lastModified()).compareTo(f2.lastModified());
    } });
```

#### Solution 2

```
public static void sortFilesDesc(File[] files) {
  Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator() {
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
      if ((File)o1).lastModified().compareTo((File)o2).lastModified()) {
        return -1;
      } else if (((File) o1).lastModified() < ((File) o2).lastModified()) {
        return +1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

### Problem

The above two solution takes more time to execute & memory. My file list consists of some 300 tar files with 200MB size each. so it is consuming more time & memory.

Is there is any way to efficiently handle this?

Every compare operation uses a file object which is of high memory is there is any way to release the memory and handle this effectively?

Comment: I think that your memory and timing issues are not due to your sorting of 300 items (which are in memory anyways). Maybe you are performing the sort more than once?

Comment: Nope i am using either of the two above mentioned solutions. what you mean by the "in memory anyways" how can i clear that once operation complete.

Comment: A `File` object is not a expensive object! It contains only the file name, not the content of the file. So the file size is totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it much faster.

Arrays.sort(...) uses "quick sort", which takes **~ n * ln(n)** operations.

This example takes only one iteration trough the whole array, which is **~ n** operations.

```
public static void sortFilesDesc(File[] files) {        
    File firstMostRecent = null;
    File secondMostRecent = null;
    File thirdMostRecent = null;
    for (File file : files) {
        if ((firstMostRecent == null)
                || (firstMostRecent.lastModified() < file.lastModified())) {
            thirdMostRecent = secondMostRecent;
            secondMostRecent = firstMostRecent;             
            firstMostRecent = file;
        } else if ((secondMostRecent == null)
                || (secondMostRecent.lastModified() < file.lastModified())) {
            thirdMostRecent = secondMostRecent;
            secondMostRecent = file;
        } else if ((thirdMostRecent == null)
                || (thirdMostRecent.lastModified() < file.lastModified())) {
            thirdMostRecent = file;
        }
    }
}
```

On small numbers of files you won't see much difference, but even for tens of files the difference will be significant, for bigger numbers - dramatic.

The code to check the algorithm (please put in a correct files structure):

```
package com.hk.basicjava.clasload.tests2;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Date;


class MyFile extends File {

    private long time = 0; 

    public MyFile(String name, long timeMills) {
        super(name);
        time = timeMills;
    }
    @Override
    public long lastModified() {
        return time;
    }
}

public class Files {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File[] files = new File[5]; 
        files[0] = new MyFile("File1", new Date(2013,1,15, 7,0).getTime());
        files[1] = new MyFile("File2", new Date(2013,1,15, 7,40).getTime());
        files[2] = new MyFile("File3", new Date(2013,1,15, 5,0).getTime());
        files[3] = new MyFile("File4", new Date(2013,1,15, 10,0).getTime());
        files[4] = new MyFile("File5", new Date(2013,1,15, 4,0).getTime());
        sortFilesDesc(files);
    }

    public static void sortFilesDesc(File[] files) {        
        File firstMostRecent = null;
        File secondMostRecent = null;
        File thirdMostRecent = null;
        for (File file : files) {
            if ((firstMostRecent == null)
                    || (firstMostRecent.lastModified() < file.lastModified())) {
                thirdMostRecent = secondMostRecent;
                secondMostRecent = firstMostRecent;             
                firstMostRecent = file;
            } else if ((secondMostRecent == null)
                    || (secondMostRecent.lastModified() < file.lastModified())) {
                thirdMostRecent = secondMostRecent;
                secondMostRecent = file;
            } else if ((thirdMostRecent == null)
                    || (thirdMostRecent.lastModified() < file.lastModified())) {
                thirdMostRecent = file;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("firstMostRecent : " + firstMostRecent.getName());
        System.out.println("secondMostRecent : " + secondMostRecent.getName());
        System.out.println("thirdMostRecent : " + thirdMostRecent.getName());
    } 

}
```

Comment: Please remove that "almost 6 times" argument. You may not compare runtimes for different algorithms by inserting numbers in the complexity formula. The conclusion is correct - but the argument is flawed.

Comment: I agree, that's not not exactly true; that's just to make people "feel the difference".

Comment: Thanks @AlexKreutznaer.  Your solution will not work for all case scenarios for Example consider the below and trace it for your algorithm.                                                        File name : FXXXXXXXXX Modified 07:00 HRS
File name : FXXXXXXXXX Modified 07:40 HRS
File name : MXXXXXXXXX Modified 05:00 HRS
File name : YXXXXXXXXX Modified 10:00 HRS<\code> 
File name : YXXXXXXXXX Modified 04:00 HRS

Comment: Why won't it work? It will work perfectly. Can you explain why do YOU think it will not work? There is nothing in you example what will make it not work.

Comment: Did you trace the algorithm? Can you give the result of your trace? I am sure there is an error in your trace. The task is very simple.

Comment: @AlexKreutznaer Please review. can some one move this to Discussion chat please ? I dont have enough points to move it

Comment: I put the code to check how it work in my answer. It has your data. Just run the code.

Comment: @AlexKreutznaer Yes i guess the new code should do it . Thanks again . I have uploaded the trace of your old code here http://txtup.net/bsdXV.

Answer (score 3):

You have to check the lastModified of every file, you cannot change that. What you don't need to do is to sort all the elements just to get the top 3. If you can use Guava, you could use [Ordering.greatestOf](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#greatestOf%28java.lang.Iterable,%20int%29) (which uses a good algorithm):

```
Ordering<File> ordering = Ordering.from( new Comparator(){
        public int compare(File f1, File f2)
        {
            return Long.valueOf(f1.lastModified()).compareTo(f2.lastModified());
        });

List<File> max3 = ordering.greatestOf(Arrays.asList(directory.listFiles()), 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am for Solution 1, with some improvements

```
Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
        public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
            long d1 = f1.lastModified();
            long d2 = f2.lastModified();
            return d1 > d2 ? 1 : d1 < d2 ? -1 : 0;
        }
    });
```

to avoid unnecessary objects creation because of Long.valueOf(long).

`File` does not hold / read any file data but only the file path, there is no performance / memory issue with it. The only time consuming operation here is reading modification time from file system which cannot be avoided.

Comment: Long.compare came in Java 7, and the question asked for a non-Java 7 solution.

Comment: Now you've changed the code to something which doesn't compile (incompatible types, int/long).

Comment: The whole issue is about efficiency, my improvement is about getting rid of creating 2 Long objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that retrieving the last modified date is a relatively expensive operation, because it involves operating system logic. So if you don't mind to get the latest up-to-date values, you could wrap your files in a comparable class.

```
public class LastModifiedFile implements Comparable<LastModifiedFile> {

    private final File file;
    private final Date lastModified;

    public LastModifiedFile(File file) {
        this.file = file;
        lastModified = file.lastModified();
    }

    public int compareTo(LastModifiedFile other) {
        return lastModified.compareTo(other.lastModified);
    }
}
```

Note that a changing last modified date during your sorting will result in undefined behavior for many sorting algorithms. Java 7s Tim Sort implementation will throw an exception, if a last modified date changes and therefore comparisons result in different values.