# Further clarification on "sorting files by last modified in java- efficient way"

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

This question is already asked here may times. Its just a reference to one of the solutions provided here at [Finding the 3 most recently modified files in a long list of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372822/sorting-files-by-last-modified-in-java-efficient-way).

I tried adding comment to the solution, but I don't have enough reputation points to comment, so I am asking it here. The solution provides a method for sorting the files by last modified.

```
public static void sortFilesDesc(File[] files) 
{        
    File firstMostRecent = null;
    File secondMostRecent = null;
    File thirdMostRecent = null;
    for (File file : files) {
        if ((firstMostRecent == null)
                || (firstMostRecent.lastModified() < file.lastModified())) {
            thirdMostRecent = secondMostRecent;
            secondMostRecent = firstMostRecent;             
            firstMostRecent = file;
        } else if ((secondMostRecent == null)
                || (secondMostRecent.lastModified() < file.lastModified())) {
            thirdMostRecent = secondMostRecent;
            secondMostRecent = file;
        } else if ((thirdMostRecent == null)
                || (thirdMostRecent.lastModified() < file.lastModified())) {
            thirdMostRecent = file;
        }
    }
}
```

The method will take array of files as argument and is suppose to sort them according to the last modified.
What I dont understand from this method is that how is it modifying the input array so that all the elements in it are sorted. In the code also we are only changing the values of the local variables firstMostRecent, secondMostRecent  and thirdMostRecent. How is the array getting modified? There might be something missing from my understanding , but I am not getting it. Please clarify my confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input Array is not modified.
This is a code for finding out 1st, 2nd & 3rd last modified files. Thats it.

After Execution of that `for` loop , you can get top 3 last  modified files.

Comment: oh ok.Nobody mentioned this in that post. The problem was to sort large number of files. I expected that it would somehow sort the whole array. thanks @vengets